# scale svg to specific width and height

Tags: svg

[image]I'm trying to display an `.svg` file to `26*28` but it is showing div to that `26*28` but not scaling the icon to specific size. I tried using `preseverveaspectratio = none` , `viewbox` and `width`/`height` attributes but it doesn't solve my problem.

`.svg` code:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 100 100" ><defs><style>.a{fill:#aeddd6;}.b{fill:none;stroke:#0d0d0d;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:2.5px;}.c{fill:#0d0d0d;}</style></defs><title>calendar</title><path class="a" d="M12.2 13.5V31H73.4V13.5H62.4s0.9 10.2-5 9.4c0 0-5.8-5.6-9.8H33.2v5.9s-1.4 4.2-5 3.9c0 0-6.2 1.2-5-9.8Z" transform="translate(-10.90282 -4.52324)"/><polyline class="b" points="51.5 8.6 62.5 8.6 62.5 67.9 1.3 67.9 1.3 8.6 12.2 8.6"/><line class="b" x1="22.3" y1="8.6" x2="41.4" y2="8.6"/><line class="b" x1="1.3" y1="26.4" x2="62.5" y2="26.4"/><circle class="c" cx="14.8" cy="40.6" r="3.1"/><circle class="c" cx="25.9" cy="40.6" r="3.1"/><circle class="c" cx="37" cy="40.6" r="3.1"/><circle class="c" cx="48.2" cy="40.6" r="3.1"/><circle class="c" cx="14.8" cy="53.1" r="3.1"/><circle class="c" cx="25.9" cy="53.1" r="3.1"/><circle class="c" cx="37" cy="53.1" r="3.1"/><circle class="c" cx="48.2" cy="53.1" r="3.1"/><rect class="b" x="12.6" y="1.3" width="9" height="16.8" rx="3.2" ry="3.2"/><rect class="b" x="42" y="1.3" width="9" height="16.8" rx="3.2" ry="3.2"/></svg>
```

SCSS

```
.calendar-icon{
  background-image: image-url('calendar.svg');
  width: 26px;
  height: 28px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```

Slim

```
.calendar-icon
```

Comment: and how are you referencing the svg?

Comment: nope @RobertLongson

Comment: @RobertLongson it doesn't solve my problem, image is loading but is not scaled to specific image 
same thing I mentioned in my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your viewBox is simply too big, resulting in lots of space to the bottom and right of your viewport.

```
viewBox="0 0 70 70"
```

is pretty close, though you might have to experiment further.

Comment: ya actual parameters are 
 width="63.75416" height="69.11493" viewBox="0 0 63.75416 69.11493"
but is not scaling to if I minimize width/height

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will experiment a bit!

Answer (score 0):

this may be a a quick fix although you can either save the svg in that size 26px 28px or try

```
.calendar-icon{
  background-image: image-url('calendar.svg');
  width: 26px !important;
  height: 28px !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}
```